# Single docker with apache2 and php-fpm over Unix socket vs 2 different containers (apache2 and php-fpm) with a TCP/IP socket?

Tags: php, performance, docker, sockets, containers

In your opinion what are the pros and cons of the two solutions?
Here's what comes to my mind:

**TCP/IP Socket with two containers**

PRO

- better scalability
- different services on different containers are more reliable in case of problems (auto-restart etc)

CONS

- worse performance (pack/unpack every request between apache and php-fpm)
- more containers (so more OSes) to manage for the physical server (greater use of ram)
- more logs (that's supposition) so more disk space used

**Unix Socket with single container**

PRO

- better performance
- fewer logs on disk

CONS

- worse scalability
- a service will be executed automatically by Docker (great reliability etc). The other could be started with some workarounds ([example](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container)). But more services in a single container is not the most recommended idea